# OSX: Terminal - Custom shortcut key combo?

Tags: macos, terminal

Any way to create a custom keyboard shortcut key (such as `ctrl+cmd+k` long as the shortcut key isn't taken already) that would store say a large snippet of text without having to download any extra programs? I have seen lots of people do this with Apps out there. But nothing with just terminal.

Comment: I'm puzzled... what's wrong with Cmd/C ?

Comment: It's something that would be great to use every day. Over and over. With out the possibility of replacing my mistake since I use my clip-board all day for other things.

Comment: that changes the complexity of the question - you need to not only copy it but keep it somewhere, presumably non-volatile, so it still works after reboot. I'll add an answer, for formatting...

Comment: Correct. Thought maybe there is something that can be placed inside the `.bash_profile` or `.profile` since these get loaded every time you boot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say cheapest way would be a text file ;-) I have reams of text files full of useful paste snippets, with nice bold headers so I can find which I need.

There are, however, many multi-clipboard utilities...

This is a recent, & fairly comprehensive list - [Clipboard Managers](http://macinchem.org/reviews/clipboard/clipboardManagers.php)

I'd say, why reinvent the wheel when so many already exist?